# Объясните порядок выполнения операций

Tags: .net

Есть выражение с наличием постинкремента.

```
int e = 0, f = e++ + 5 * e;
Console.WriteLine($"e = {e}, f = {f}");
```

В итоге выводит `e = 1, f = 5` хотя по логике

1. 5 умножаем на `e` т.е. `5*0 = 0`
2. `e + 0 = 0`  значит `f = 0`
3. увеличиваем `e++` значит `e = 1`

Итог: по моей логике `е = 1, f = 0`

Answer (score 2):

Ваша логика неверна, ибо постфиксный инкремент (...++) имеет в данном выражении наибольший приоритет и действует он так - значение операнда возвращается, а затем увеличивается на единицу.

Таким образом:

1. Возвращаем **e** (0) на место **e++**
2. Увеличиваем  **e** на единицу
3. Умножаем
4. Складываем